# Does libx265 and libx264 libraries implement a decoder?

Tags: x264, libx264, libx265

I have one question about these 2 codec library developped by videolan.

Does x265(libx265) implements a decoder?
Same question for x264(libx264).

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

No, for both x264 and x265. If you need decoder than you better to look for ffmpeg/libav projects.